# Footer Links in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, layout, blocks, xml

If you can not tell by this question I will out right tell you I am still trying to figure out the Magento layout.

I need to modify the footer links but under CMS > Static Blocks, in the wysiwyg, I find `footer_links` enabled but the content is of default settings + it is commented out:

```
    `<!--
     <ul>
     <li><a href="{{store direct_url="about-magento-demo-store"}}">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="{{store direct_url="customer-service"}}">Customer Service</a></li>
     <li> class="last privacy"><a href="{{store direct_url="privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"}}">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     </ul>
     -->`
```

The links that exist in the footer, such as "SITE MAP, SEARCH TERMS, ADVANCED SEARCH, ORDERS AND RETURNS, CONTACT US", I can not find anywhere.

I have searched many of the xml files but I am not even sure if that is where I need to find them. Am I going down the correct path? `app/design/frontend/[template-name]/default/layout/` or `.../template/`?

I am baffled. Can anyone help point the way here?

Answer (score 1):

The links you mentioned are added to the footer via layout xml files.
For example the Search terms link is added from `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/catalogseach.xml` with this code

```
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
            <label>Search Terms</label>
            <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
            <title>Search Terms</title>
        </action>
```

Remove that and the link should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable template hints under `system->configuration->developer` for particular store, if this code added in template it shows the template path over there.